# Accessing a Rails model name from within a lib file of the same method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This may seem like a silly question but I have a model named Ad and I have a library name auto which contains a class Ad(lib/auto.rb).

```
#auto.rb lib file
module auto
 class Ad
   def initialize 
    ...
   end

   def convert
    # here I would like to access my model class Ad
    # ::Ad does not work. Requiring it does not work either.
   end


 end
end
```

Does Rails 3 store models under some global namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something or you are defining `auto::Ad?`
If so, then `::Ad` will never work. use `auto::Ad` or `Ad` (from within the `auto` module).
If you really don't want the `auto` namespace . Remvoe the `module auto` part in your code.

Comment: What I am trying to call is the model class Ad which lives in app/models/ad. So within a method that lives in module::Ad#self.some_method I want to instantiate an object that belongs to class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't get it straight from your external class. But you can pass it from your exact model.

I think this can be useful

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#add-an-acts_as-method-to-active-record